# How to pass helm chart credentials in Kustomization

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kustomize

Error: Error: looks like "https://jfrog-prod.debs.cloud/artifactory/helm-dev2-local/helm-sample/nginx-sample.tgz" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://jfrog-prod.debs.cloud/artifactory/helm-dev2-local/helm-sample/nginx-sample.tgz/index.yaml : 401 Unauthorized. it would need credentials. I don't see any option to password credentials in

> kustomize build . --enable-helm

I'm trying to use helm charts in kustomization.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

helmCharts:
  - name: minecraft
    includeCRDs: false
    valuesFile: values.yaml
    releaseName: moria
    version: 0.1.0
    repo: https://jfrog-prod.debs.cloud/artifactory/helm-dev2-local/helm-sample/nginx-sample.tgz
```

**Expectation**
kustomize build . --enable-helm command should print deployment and service object.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar problem and as far as I know there is currently no official* way to use private storage, registry authentication or OCI registries using `--enable-helm` with Kustomize.

However, you could try your luck with Helm's `--post-renderer`. I found [this guide](https://alysivji.github.io/helm-post-rendering-hook.html) to be very helpful.

*from [Kustomize documentation](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/helmcharts/#long-term-support):

> ### Long term support
>
> The helm chart inflation generator in kustomize is intended to be a limited subset of helm features to help with getting started with kustomize, and we cannot support the entire helm feature set.
>
> #### The current builtin
>
> For enhancements to the helm chart inflation generator feature, we will only support the following changes:
>
> - bug fixes
> - critical security issues
> - additional fields that are analogous to flags passed to `helm template`, except for flags such as `post-renderer` that allow arbitrary commands to be executed
>
> We will not add support for:
>
> - private repository or registry authentication
> - OCI registries
> - other large features that increase the complexity of the feature and/or have significant security implications
>
> #### Future support
>
> The next iteration of the helm inflation generator will take the form of a KRM function, which will have no such restrictions on what types of features we can add and support. You can see more details in the [Helm support long term plan](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4401).